# find a nonconstant function $f$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq |y - x|$ and part b)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

**a)** find a function $f$, other than a constant function such that $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq |y - x|$

**b)** Suppose $f(y) - f(x) \leq (y - x)^2$ Prove that $f$ is a constant function.

**Solutions:** I had troubles with this whole problem including the first part.I think I don't understand what the question is trying to achieve. I am aware that there have been multiple solutions posted for part b), but there is still some things I do  not understand, so I am going to write out a solution and ask about those specifics.

*a)* the solution given was to let $f(x) = x$ but this gives me $|x - f(y)| \leq |y-x|$ I'm not really sure what that really says except allowing me to compare $f(y)\ and\ y$ I suppose based upon the original expression given that this would be true.

*b)* This is where I was having issues.

$$\left|f(y) - f(x)\right| = \left|\sum_{k = 1}^{n} f\left( x + \frac{k}{n}[y-x]\right) - f\left(x + \frac{k-1}{n}[y-x]\right)\right|$$

I was trying to work this out to arrive at $$\left|f(y) - f(x)\right|$$ but the closest I could get was: $$f(y) - f\left( \frac{y(n-1) + x}{n}\right)$$

So I don't see the way that they "added zero" to the solution.

The second portion that confused me was: $$\sum_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{n^2}(y-x)^2$$ What was the motivation for this expression? I see that it will reduce to: $$\frac{(y-x)^2}{n}$$

then the conclusion follows that:  "therefore $f(x) = f(y)$". How does that imply a constant function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write out the summation
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{n} f\left( x + \frac{k}{n}[y-x]\right) - f\left(x + \frac{k-1}{n}[y-x]\right),
$$
letting $k$ take value $1$, $2$, $3$, $\ldots$, $n$ in turn. For $k=1$ you get
$$f\left( x + \frac{1}{n}[y-x]\right) - f\left(x + \frac{0}{n}[y-x]\right),$$
for $k=2$ you get
$$f\left( x + \frac{2}{n}[y-x]\right) - f\left(x + \frac{1}{n}[y-x]\right),$$
for $k=3$ you get
$$f\left( x + \frac{3}{n}[y-x]\right) - f\left(x + \frac{2}{n}[y-x]\right),$$
and so on. For $k=n$ you get
$$f\left( x + \frac{n}{n}[y-x]\right) - f\left(x + \frac{n-1}{n}[y-x]\right).$$
Notice the first term in one row cancels the second term in the next row, so all that remains is the second term in the top row and the first term in the bottom row, i.e.,
$$f\left( x + \frac{n}{n}[y-x]\right) - f\left(x + \frac{0}{n}[y-x]\right).$$
This simplifies to $f(y)-f(x)$.

To finish the proof: We've established that
$$|f(y)-f(x)|\le{(y-x)^2\over n}\tag1$$
without specifying what $n$ was. Since it's true for all $n$, this means the LHS of (1) is less than a quantity we can make as small as we please (by choosing $n$ as large as necessary). Since absolute values are non-negative, we conclude the LHS of (1) must equal zero:
$$|f(y)-f(x)| = 0$$
and therefore $f(y)=f(x)$. Since $x$ and $y$ were also arbitrary, it follows that the function $f$ takes the same value at every $x$ and $y$, hence $f$ is constant.

Comment: Thank you for the effort put into writing this solution out. I should've noticed the telescoping sums....

Answer (score 1):

For a):

$f(t)=t$ is a good example, it gives $|x-y|\le|y-x|$ what is true.

---

For b):

you have $\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right|\le|x-y|$ for all $x,y$, $x\neq y$.

Apply $\lim_{y\to x}$ to both sides to get $|f'(x)|=0$. This happens for all $x$, so$f=const.$

Comment: That's the derivative approach, I was trying to understand it without taking the limit.